# The tag `img` is not a recognized Liquid tag GitHub pages with Octopress

Tags: jekyll, octopress, github-pages

I have created a post which has some image tags. These images are getting displayed at local `rake preview`. 
Here is the code in the post

`{% img left /images/books_1.png 220 300 %}
{% img left /images/books_2.png 220 300 %}
{% img  /images/books_3.png 220 300 %}`

But when I push to github pages. Git hub sent me build failure error saying.
`The tag img in 'source/_posts/2014-11-29-pages.markdown/#excerpt' is not a recognized Liquid tag`.
Am i need to add any plugin to use `img` tag in github pages?

Comment: Use `rake generate` and `rake deploy`. Remember that HTML is a publishing format and Markdown is a writing format. You need to **generate** your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

This bit me recently when I updated my blog and started getting page build errors all of a sudden.  It turns out that GitHub Pages recently changed to  [automatically build any content included in the repo](https://github.com/blog/2289-publishing-with-github-pages-now-as-easy-as-1-2-3).

The reason it fails is that Octopress is not supported (directly) by GH pages -- GH Pages supports a [relatively small number of plugins](https://pages.github.com/versions/), and Octopress is not one of them.

The solution for me was to create and commit a file named ".nojekyll" in the root of the blog (as mentioned in the link).

Just to be clear -- when you use Octopress you're generating all the html for the blog locally and pushing that generated html to GitHub Pages.  So, GH doesn't need to do any rendering on the markdown files -- that is all being done on your local machine, before GH ever sees it.

Octopress does, however, also commit your blog source to the repo (specifically the "rake deploy" command) -- and with the change to GH Pages, GH tries (and fails) to render the markdown files.  The .nojekyll file turns that off, and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run octopress plugins on Github pages ([see allowed plugins here](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-plugins-with-github-pages/)).

You must use the 'rake generate && rake deploy' command ([see Octopress documentation here](http://octopress.org/docs/deploying/github/))